# Calculate the difference between the sum of hours in a group of time stamps and a fixed number

Tags: pandas, timestamp, difference

I have the following dataframe.  What I am trying to achieve is for each ‘Date_worked’, the sum of the hours in the ‘Time_spent’ column should equal to 7.  For example, on 6/10/2019 the sum of the hours is already 7, so nothing needs to be adjusted. On 6/12/2019, the sum of the hours is 4.25, so I need to insert a row with a ‘Tab_description’ ‘Difference’, which would show as the difference of 2.75 under the ‘Time_spent’. 6/13/2019 and 6/14/2019 already amount to 7, so nothing needs to be done there.  In the case of 6/19/2019, I need to do the same as in 6/12/2019, insert a row with a sum of 6 to make the total sum up to 7. Thanks for your help.

```
Date_worked Tab_description Time_spent
    0   6/10/2019   Perform planning procedures 7.0
    1   6/11/2019   Perform planning procedures 7.0
    2   6/12/2019   Time off (away from the office) 2.25
    3   6/12/2019   Staff meeting   1.0
    4   6/12/2019   Accounting & Risk Management Luncheon   1.0
    5   6/13/2019   Perform planning procedures 7.0
    6   6/14/2019   Time off (away from the office) 2.0
    7   6/14/2019   Review policies and procedures  5.0
    8   6/17/2019   Time off (away from the office) 7.0
    9   6/18/2019   Perform planning procedures 7.0
    10  6/19/2019   Staff meeting   1.0
    11  6/20/2019   Time off (away from the office) 2.0
    12  6/21/2019   Time off (away from the office) 1.0
    13  6/24/2019   Staff meeting (FY 20 planning)  7.0
    14  6/25/2019   FCR Kick-off meeting    1.0
    15  6/26/2019   Time off (away from the office) 1.5
    16  6/26/2019   Staff meeting   1.0
    17  6/28/2019   Time off (away from the office) 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, I will show you using `groupby` & `concat`.

first let us work out the total time and difference,

```
print(df)
      Date_worked                           Tab_description  Time_spent
0    6/10/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
1    6/11/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
2    6/12/2019          Time off (away from the office)         0.25
3    6/12/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
4    6/12/2019  Accounting & Risk Management Luncheon           1.00
5    6/13/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
6    6/14/2019          Time off (away from the office)         2.00
7    6/14/2019          Review policies and procedures          5.00
8    6/17/2019          Time off (away from the office)         7.00
9    6/18/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
10   6/19/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
11   6/20/2019          Time off (away from the office)         2.00
12   6/21/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.00
13   6/24/2019                        Staff meeting (FY         7.00
14   6/25/2019                  FCR Kick-off meeting            1.00
15   6/26/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.50
16   6/26/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
17   6/28/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.00
```

we start with `groupby` and a simple difference sum, we assign this to a new variable called df2.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Date_worked')['Time_spent'].sum().reset_index()
df2['variance'] = df2['Time_spent'] - 7.00
```

we now create your tab column and create description you asked for,

```
df2.loc[df2['variance'] != 0, 'Tab_description'] = 'Difference'
```

we then drop any NaN rows, drop the `'Time_spent'` column, and rename the 'Variance' column to timespent within a `concat`.

```
pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df2.dropna()
        .drop("Time_spent", axis=1)
        .rename(columns={"variance": "Time_spent"}),
    ],
    sort=False,
)
print(df)


  Date_worked                           Tab_description  Time_spent
0    6/10/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
1    6/11/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
2    6/12/2019          Time off (away from the office)         0.25
3    6/12/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
4    6/12/2019  Accounting & Risk Management Luncheon           1.00
5    6/13/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
6    6/14/2019          Time off (away from the office)         2.00
7    6/14/2019          Review policies and procedures          5.00
8    6/17/2019          Time off (away from the office)         7.00
9    6/18/2019              Perform planning procedures         7.00
10   6/19/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
11   6/20/2019          Time off (away from the office)         2.00
12   6/21/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.00
13   6/24/2019                        Staff meeting (FY         7.00
14   6/25/2019                  FCR Kick-off meeting            1.00
15   6/26/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.50
16   6/26/2019                          Staff meeting           1.00
17   6/28/2019          Time off (away from the office)         1.00
2    6/12/2019                                Difference       -4.75
7    6/19/2019                                Difference       -6.00
8    6/20/2019                                Difference       -5.00
9    6/21/2019                                Difference       -6.00
11   6/25/2019                                Difference       -6.00
12   6/26/2019                                Difference       -4.50
13   6/28/2019                                Difference       -6.00
```

Comment: @Nev1111 happy to help, I've spent alot of time with time sheet and labour data. If this answer is sufficient feel free to green tick so the question can be closed